# split sentences from paragraph into individual cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I have text data that I want to parse. The data is split into cells but each cell contains more that just one sentence. I want to isolate the sentences into individual cells to make parsing easier.

I used the formula below to count sentences in a given cell and it works well, so I'd assume ". " can be used to demarcate sentences.

```
=LEN(D2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2,".",""))
```

So now I would like to split the content of these cells containing text, and copy each sentences (separately, in their own cell) to a row on a different sheet. Each row would correspond to one text cell in the previous sheet.

[image: See the illustration]

Any idea of how I should proceed? Thank you!

Comment: 1) What exactly is your desired output? have each sentence in its own cell on the same line, or have them in new rows below the original? 2) Just a quick note that `!`, `?` and `...` can also end sentences.

Comment: each sentence in its own cell. all the sentences from the same (original) cell on the same row. The output on a sheet distinct from the input.

Comment: Have you tried using `Text to Columns`?

Comment: I just did, thanks! The issue now is that there are in fact `?` demarcating sentences in my data... I can use the `Custom` option of `Text to Columns` for sentences ending in `. `, but once the sentences are split it seems that I can't use `Text to Columns` a second time to split sentences ending in `? ` - I'm thinking of using tokens such as `*.` for `. ` and `**.` for  `? ` so I could split and then recover the specific symbols via the `find and replace` command. would there be a more straightforward option?

Comment: Why would you not be able to run the `Text to Columns` operation a second time, in order to split on ? ?. Just select the whole output area of the first run and enter the question mark in the `Custom` option.

Comment: @supagleech, where is paragraph & Sentence? Your screen shot shows that you want split Decimal separated values on other Sheet. Title & body text are not co-relating each other do some correction first !!